# Let f be a differentiable function with f(0)=0 and f(1)=1, f'(0)=f'(1)=0. Prove that |f''(x)| > 4 for some x in (0,1). (Without invoking integrals)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.
Also, $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$.
Prove that $f''(x)>4$ for some $x \in (0,1)$.

Any help would​ be appreciated. 
My initial attempts were using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem first between $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ to show that $f'(t)=1$ for some $t$ in $(0,1)$. 
Now applying LMV between $f'(t)$ and $f'(0)$, and $f'(t)$ and $f'(1)$ I could prove it if t lies in either $(0,1/4]$ or in $[3/4,1)$.
Don't really know where to go next.

Comment: @md2perpe well that was my question that was closed as a duplicate. The linked questions all involve integrals.

Comment: @peterwhy, I also took that function as a counter example, but now found that it's not twice differentiable at $x=\frac12$. I thought that it was twice differentiable but that $f''$ just wasn't continuous as $x=\frac12$.

Comment: @md2perpe Twice differentiability condition was added after my comment.

Comment: @peterwhy I apologise for that, the title was running out of characters and I missed it in the body

Comment: @peterwhy. Okay, I took it from Ritik Garg's previous question.

Comment: @Ritik Garg I'm sorry if this may sound a bit blunt, but... Well, let me explain: forbidding integrals may make sense in a contest, so that participants who didn't study calculus yet have equal chances. But forbidding integrals when derivatives are allowed and used is ludicrous. I hope I'm allowed using both hands while typing this.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, forbidding integrals is like having to use traditional integrals instead of residue calculus for solving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \, dx$.

Comment: @md2perpe No, it isn't. Excluding complex analysis for calculating real integrals _may_ make sense (not in my world: when people are grown up, i.e. beyond high school, they use professional tools to solve professional problems). Excluding parts of real analysis while accepting other parts does _not_ make sense.

Comment: Your previous question was marked duplicate and you should have seen the original question. That question was solved via integrals, but there were other questions linked to it which were solved without integrals.  For example see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1138950/72031

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$1 = |f(1) - f(0)| \leqslant |f(1/2) - f(0)| + |f(1/2) - f(1)|,$$

and by Taylor's theorem there exist $c_1 \in (0,1/2)$ and $c_2 \in (1/2,1)$ such that

$$f(1/2) = f(0) + \frac{1}{2} f''(c_1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2, \\ f(1/2) = f(1) + \frac{1}{2} f''(c_2)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$

Hence,

$$1 \leqslant \frac{1}{8} (\, |f''(c_1)| + |f''(c_2)|\,) \leqslant \frac{1}{4} \max (|f''(c_1)|, |f''(c_2)|)$$

Your result follows.

Comment: That proves that $f''(x) \geq 4$ for some $x \in (0, 1)$. In the question the inequality is strict: $f''(x) > 4$.

Comment: @md2perpe all previous versions give non-strict inequality, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835042/f0-f0-f1-0-and-f1-1-implies-maxf-geq-4 for example. Interesting to try to get close to $4,$ maybe even achieve $4.$ The simple $-2 x^3 + 3 x^2$ gives second derivative $\pm 6$ at the endpoints.

Comment: Taking $f(x) = 2x^2$ for $x \in [0, \frac12]$ and $f(x) = 1-2x^2$ for $x \in [\frac12, 1]$ gives $|f''(x)| = 4$ when $x \in (0, 1)\setminus\{\frac12\}.$ However $f''(\frac12)$ isn't defined.

Comment: From Shifrin's argument at the linked version, your example is optimal in one sense, meaning that demanding $C^2$ forces strict inequality. Backwards, what is the infimum when demanding $C^2,$ as it may not be achievable...

Comment: I get it, revise yours to $(2 + \delta )x^2$ and $1 - (2 + \delta)x^2,$ smooth out in a small neighborhood of $1/2.$ So $4$ is the infimum

Answer (score 2):

Curious about how much work it is to get close to the boundary value. Easier to switch domain and range to $[-1,1]$ and try to keep $|f''|$ not much larger than 2.

Here is a version of the question with built in scaling: [Prove that $|f''(\xi)|\geqslant\frac{4|f(a)-f(b)|}{(b-a)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557599/prove-that-f-xi-geqslant-frac4fa-fbb-a2)

Here is an example of a quintic, not bad. Red is the quintic, second derivative is green. As I said, we are taking $-1 \leq x \leq 1.$ Let's see, $a=-1, \; f(a)=-1, \; b = 1, \; f(b) = 1.$ So
$$ \frac{4|f(b)-f(a)|}{(b-a)^2} = 2. $$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will use the fact the if $f(0) \leq g(0)$, $f'(0) \leq g'(0)$ and $f''(t) \leq g''(t)$ when $0 < t < x$ then $f(x) \leq g(x)$ with equality iff $f = g$.

Suppose that $f$ is twice differentiable, $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = 0$ and that $f''(t) \leq 4$ for all $t \in (0, 1).$ Then, taking $g(t) = 2t^2$ in the above fact, we have $f(x) \leq 2x^2$ and especially $f(\frac12) \leq \frac12$ with equality iff $f(t) = 2t^2$ for $t \in [0, \frac12]$. Applying the fact on $\hat f(t) = 1 - f(1-t)$ and $\hat g(t) = 1 - g(1-t)$ gives $\hat f(\frac12) \leq \hat g(\frac12)$, i.e. $f(\frac12) \geq \frac12$ with equality iff $f(t) = 1-2t^2$ for $t \in [\frac12, 1]$.

Thus, for $f$ to be continuous at $\frac12$ we must have $f(t) = 2t^2$ for $t \in [0, \frac12]$ and $f(t) = 1-2t^2$ for $t \in [\frac12, 1]$. However, $f''(\frac12)$ is not defined for this function, which contradicts our assumption.

Therefore, some assumption must be invalid. The assumptions that $f$ is twice differentiable, and that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$, are given. Therefore the assumption $f''(t) \leq 4$ for all $t \in (0, 1)$ must be taken as invalid. Thus there must be some point $x \in (0, 1)$ where $f''(x) > 4$.

Comment: The fact I have used can be proved by taking $h = f-g$ so that $h(0) \leq 0$, $h'(0) \leq 0$ and $h''(t) \leq 0$ when $0 < t < x$. Applying the mean value theorem (mvt) gives $h'(x) = h'(0) + x h''(\xi) \leq 0$ and then a second application of mvt gives $h(x) = h(0) + x h'(\eta) \leq 0$. Thus $f(x) \leq g(x)$.

Comment: Could you please explain how you arrived at : $\hat f(\frac12) \leq \hat g(\frac12)$,

Comment: @MathMan. I used the fact given in my first paragraph applied on $\hat f$ and $\hat g$ at $x = \frac12.$

Comment: Can you take me through the steps because I still get $f(1/2 ) \le1/2$

Comment: Do you get that $\hat f(\frac12) \leq \hat g(\frac12)$? Then $f(\frac12) = 1 - \hat f(\frac12) \geq 1 - \hat g(\frac12) = \frac12.$

Comment: Nope. I couldn't derive why this was true...

Comment: I now see that I in fact made a mistake. I should have compared $\hat f$ with $g$. We have $\hat f(0) = 0 = g(0)$, $\hat f'(0) = 0 = g'(0)$ and $\hat f''(t) = f''(t) \leq 4 = g''(t)$ for all $t \in (0, 1).$ Then, by the fact, $\hat f(\frac12) \leq g(\frac12) = \frac12$ which gives $f(\frac12) = 1 - \hat f(1 - \frac12) \geq 1 - \frac12 = \frac12.$

Comment: Could you please explain now, the last part only where you argued that $f$ must be $1-2 t^2$. Thanks again lot

Comment: @MathMan. It seems like I hade made another error; it should be $f(t) = 1 - 2(1-t)^2.$